# Optimizing Google Earth Engine code

Tags: google-earth-engine, google-earth-engine-javascript-api, code-review

How can I optimize this code? I know using .getInfo is bad, but I'm not sure how to work around that

```
var dataset = ee.ImageCollection('USDA/NAIP/DOQQ')
                  .filter(ee.Filter.date('2021-01-01', '2023-06-01')).select(['R', 'G', 'B']);
var urls = []
//coords is an imported csv with longitude and latitudes
var coordsList = coords.geometry().coordinates()

for(var i=0; i<100; i++) {
  //define the point around which we want to get the image
  var point = ee.Geometry.Point(coordsList.get(i))
  
  //define the area around the point we want to capture
  var bbox = point.buffer(ee.Number(size).sqrt().divide(2), 1).bounds()
  
  //make sure our imagery only captures the desired area
  var intersect = dataset.filterBounds(bbox).mosaic()//.clip(bbox)
  
  if(intersect.bandNames().size().getInfo() > 0){
    var url = intersect.getThumbURL({
        'region': bbox,
        'dimensions': '1000x1000',
        'format': 'png'})
    urls.push(url)
  }
}
print(urls)
```

I'm checking to see how many bands each image has, since the imagery I am using doesn't have coverage for all the coordinates in my list. If it has no bands, .getThumbURL() will throw an error, so I have to make sure the number of bands is above 0.

This code takes a couple minutes to run, but since I have to do 10000 images and right now I'm only exporting about 70, I want to try to speed it up.

Comment: how are you exporting the images? your code only ends with printing of urls so is there any other code that you use for exporting?

Comment: @prusswan I'm just generating the links, I'm going to use Python with multiprocessing to actually download all of it. I'm considering doing the same thing to generate the URLs but I just wanted to see if I could make this any faster.

Comment: Why do you need the **ThumbURL** if there is an easier way to know if there are images for each point or not? (mapping Feature and Image Collections). The **getThumbURL** method is also bad because it cannot be used in mapped functions. So, you necessarily have to use for-loop, getInfo and  getThumbURL not recommend methods.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The 'getThumbURL' method is also bad because it cannot be used in mapped functions. So, you necessarily have to use **for-loop**, **getInfo** and **getThumbURL** not recommend methods. For testing your approach, I produced 10,000 random points in USA territory (excluding Alaska and insular territories) and I ran the code slightly modified as follows. Process was aborted for 10000 points, however, it ran for 1000 points taking about 15 minutes for generating the links and two minutes for exporting them to Google Drive.

```
var randomPoints_list = randomPoints.toList(randomPoints.size());

var urls = [];

var size = 1000000;

for(var i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {  
    //define the point around which we want to get the image
  //var point = ee.Geometry.Point(ee.List(coordsList).get(i));
  var point = ee.Feature(randomPoints_list.get(i)).geometry();
  
  //define the area around the point we want to capture
  var bbox = point.buffer(ee.Number(size).sqrt().divide(2), 1);
  
  //make sure our imagery only captures the desired area
  var intersect = dataset.filterBounds(bbox).mosaic();
  
  if(intersect.bandNames().size().getInfo() > 0){
    var url = intersect.getThumbURL({
        'region': bbox,
        'scale': 2,
        'format': 'png'});
    urls.push(url);
  }
}

var feats = urls.map(function (ele) {
  
  return ee.Feature(null).set({'urls': ele});
  
});

print(urls);

print(feats);

Export.table.toDrive({
  collection: ee.FeatureCollection(feats),
  description: 'urls',
  folder: 'GEE_Folder'
});
```

On the other hand, I also tested my approach mapping Feature and Image Collections. It looks as follows:

```
var dataset = ee.ImageCollection('USDA/NAIP/DOQQ')
                  .filter(ee.Filter.date('2021-01-01', '2023-06-01'))
                  .select(['R', 'G', 'B']);

var randomPoints = ee.FeatureCollection.randomPoints(
    {region: region, points: 10000, seed: 0, maxError: 1});

Map.centerObject(region, 4);
Map.addLayer(randomPoints, {color: 'blue'}, 'Random points');

var allImg = randomPoints.map(function (ele){
  
  var intersect = dataset.filterBounds(ee.Feature(ele).geometry());
  
  var opt = ee.Algorithms.If(ee.Number(intersect.size()).gt(0), 
                                       intersect, 
                                       ee.ImageCollection(ee.Image().set({'system:time_start': ee.Date(0).format().slice(0, 10),
                                                                          'id': '0'
                                                                          })));
  
  opt = ee.FeatureCollection(opt).map(function (img) {
    
    return img.set('point_coor', ee.Feature(ele).geometry().coordinates());
    
  });
  
  return opt;
  
});

print(allImg.size());

allImg = allImg.flatten();

//print(allImg.size());

var test = ee.ImageCollection(allImg);

//print(test.limit(2));

var indexes = ee.List(allImg.aggregate_array('system:index'));
var ids = ee.List.sequence(0, indexes.size().subtract(1));
var idByIndex = ee.Dictionary.fromLists(indexes, ids);

var my_feats = test.map(function (ele) {
  
  var id = ee.String(ee.Image(ele).id());
  var coor = ee.Image(ele).get('point_coor');
  var date = ee.Image(ele).get('system:time_start');
  
  return ee.Feature(null).set({'date': ee.Date(date).format().slice(0, 10),
                               'id': idByIndex.get(ele.get('system:index')),
                               'name_image': ee.String('USDA/NAIP/DOQQ/').cat(id), 
                               'point_coor': coor});
  
});

//print(my_feats.first());

Export.table.toDrive({
  collection: my_feats,
  description: 'image_names',
  folder: 'GEE_Folder'
});
```

After running complete code [here](https://code.earthengine.google.com/8b725eb06e32a466b3a9a3f9b137b47d) (for-loop lines are also included but commented), result for the task was obtained only in a couple of minutes for 10,000 points producing information for points with or without images. Used points can be observed in following picture.

[image]

An extract of exported CSV file, with 12,122 records, it is at following picture. This CSV file has 'system:index', 'date', 'id', 'image_names' and point coordinates fields. Records inside red rectangles correspond to points without any image (id has no sense and the date is always 1/1/1970). Records inside green rectangle correspond to tree images for the same point.

[image]